# How to Create a URL in Controller like HtmlHelper

Tags: cakephp, html-helper, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-3.x

**TLDR:** How can I create a URL in the Controller similar to how I can use the HtmlHelper to create URLs in a View?

---

**Problem:**

I want to print the url of a controller action, in my controller (because I create my JSON string in my controller, not in a view)

In a `View`, I can use `$this->Html->url()`, but what about in a Controller?

Should I use defined constant like `APP_DIR` + Controller name + Controller action?)

Answer (score 37):

Use the Router class.

```
$url = Router::url([
    'controller' => 'Articles',
    'action' => 'index',
    '?' => ['page' => 1],
    '#' => 'top'
]);
```

or the same thing, but in a more common/simple scenario:

```
$url = Router::url(['controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index']);
```

Note: in Cake2.x, "Articles" would be lowercase.

---

**[CakePHP 2.x Router documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router::url)**

**[CakePHP 3.x 'Generating URLs' documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls)**

Comment: Remember to use the routing class: `use Cake\Routing\Router;`